# An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication

I have created UserDetailsServiceImpl. Here I get the user name and the role of this user. But I couldn't understand what the problem was. I've tried the sql query in the database.

---

SecurityConfig.java

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
};

@Autowired
protected void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/", "/veteriner").permitAll().antMatchers("/**")
            .hasRole("ADMIN").and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/login/login-status-success")
            .failureUrl("/login/login-status-error").permitAll().usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password").and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true).permitAll().and().csrf();
}
```

---

LoginController.java

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public class LoginController {

 @GetMapping
 public ModelAndView home() throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("login");
    return mv;
}

@RequestMapping(path="/login-status-error",method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView erorLogin() throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("main");
    return mv;
}

@RequestMapping(path="/login-status-succes",method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView succesLogin() throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("veteriner");
    return mv;
}
```

}

---

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    com.model.User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found.");
    }

    User securityUser = new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true,
            buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRoles()));
    return securityUser;
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(List<User_role> userRoles) {
    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

    for (User_role userRole : userRoles) {
        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole().getRoleName()));
    }

    List<GrantedAuthority> results = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);
    return results;
}
```

---

> select user0_.id as id1_6_, user0_.email as email2_6_, user0_.password as password3_6_, user0_.username as username4_6_ from public."User" user0_ where user0_.username=?
>   16:37:16.930 [http-nio-8186-exec-12] ERROR org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.model.User
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:123) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.16]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.16]
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71) [log4j-web-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.16]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.16]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) [catalina.jar:9.0.16]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.16]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [catalina.jar:9.0.16]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [catalina.jar:9.0.16]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.16]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668) [catalina.jar:9.0.16]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [catalina.jar:9.0.16]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.16]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.16]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.16]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.16]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.16]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.16]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_202]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_202]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.16]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_202]
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.model.User
>       at com.dao.UserDaoImpl.findByUsername(UserDaoImpl.java:23) ~[classes/:?]
>       at com.service.UserServiceImpl.findByUsername(UserServiceImpl.java:26) ~[classes/:?]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy238.findByUsername(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
>       at com.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailsServiceImpl.java:29) ~[classes/:?]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy239.loadUserByUsername(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:108) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       ... 45 more

---

Comment: Your code is huge and your explanations are minimal. This is borderline unacceptable. Please check how to create [MINIMAL, complete, and verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: One mistake I found that you don't place @Configuration in given SecurityConfig.java class. You declare bean inside it so I hope you have to define that.

Answer (score 0):

There's too much going on for me to follow, but I think it's simply the case that you can't both create and inject the same bean in the same class.

I.e.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {...}
}
```

won't work. Just think about it, you need `UserDetailsService` to create the class that's supposed to create `UserDetailsService`. How would that work?

You can do this instead:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com")
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return super.userDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider getDaoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        //call the userDetailsService() method here
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    ...

}
```

While this looks weird, it does the right thing. Spring proxies all method calls, so when you seemingly call `userDetailsService()` directly, it actually injects the appropriate bean instead.